# How can you make the postal code field in the Adyen web drop in not case sensitive?

Tags: adyen

The postal code entry in Adyen is far too strict and provides a bad experience to users in the web drop in. How can this be configured to allow lower case? Other payment providers have no problem allowing lower case letters in a Canadian postal code...

Comment: which version of the drop-in are you using? and which payment method?